# Compare JSON response using JUnit and JSONassert

Tags: java, json, junit, jsonassert

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm asking to write test of JSON response server.
I found [JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) very useful but I didn't succeed to write the method `getRESTData`.

Anybody can help please?

```
@Test
public void testGetFriends() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject data =  getRESTData("/friends/367.json");
    String expected = "{friends:[{id:123,name:\"Corby Page\"}"
            + ",{id:456,name:\"Solomon Duskis\"}]}";
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, data, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your question macias. I don't know how to convert the url requested into json. In my example how i can get the json "/friends/367.json" from the url.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the data as `String` and pass it into `JSONAssert.assertEquals`. 
Converting to `JSONObject` isn't necessary.

To fetch data from an URL, you can use `URL.getContent` method:

```
final String data = new URL("...").getContent();
String expected = "{friends:[{id:123,name:\"Corby Page\"}"
        + ",{id:456,name:\"Solomon Duskis\"}]}";
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, data, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved with ModelAssert - https://github.com/webcompere/model-assert , which can take anything serializable to JSON as an input:

```java
@Test
public void testGetFriends() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject data =  getRESTData("/friends/367.json");
    String expected = "{friends:[{id:123,name:\"Corby Page\"}"
            + ",{id:456,name:\"Solomon Duskis\"}]}";
    
    assertJson(data).isEqualTo(expected);
}
```

IIRC `JSONObject` is essentially a `Map`, so `assertJson` will convert it to the internal `JsonNode` format it uses for comparison.